# Spring Boot stops resolving views after a few minutes

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app which all of a sudden stops resolving views and instead throws 404 errors at me.

These are my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jasper -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate validator -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- BoneCP -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
        <version>${bonecp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySql Java Connector -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The app starts fine, and lets me browse without any issue. However if I stop looking at it and just continue doing stuff, when I refresh the web browser I see a Tomcat 404 page:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp

type: Status report
message: /WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp
description: The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
```

Home controller (Although every controller that returns a view fails):

```
@Controller
public class ProjectOutputController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectOutputController.class);
    private final ProjectOutputService projectOutputService;

    @Value("${app.version}")
    private String appVersion;

    @Inject
    public ProjectOutputController(final ProjectOutputService projectOutputService) {
        this.projectOutputService = projectOutputService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/", "/home", "/results"})
    public ModelAndView getHomeView(){

        LOGGER.trace("Returning main view");
        ModelMap map = new ModelMap();
        List<ProjectOutput> projectOutputs = projectOutputService.getProjects();

        map.addAttribute("projects", projectOutputs);
        map.addAttribute("appVersion", appVersion);
        return new ModelAndView("home",map);
    }
```

This one works, however, as it does not return a view but a raw JSON as string

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value={"/overview/{projectId}"}, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ProjectOverview> showProjectJson(@PathVariable String projectId) {
    LOGGER.trace("Returning JSON for project ID " + projectId + " view");
    try {
        return new ResponseEntity<> (projectOverviewService.getProjectbyId(projectId), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (ProjectOverviewNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Project not found - " + e);
        return new ResponseEntity<> (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}

}
```

Spring Boot's trace log:

```
2016-03-18 12:49:26 TRACE o.s.w.s.v.InternalResourceViewResolver:164 - Cached view [home]
2016-03-18 12:49:26 DEBUG o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver:402 - Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'home'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2016-03-18 12:49:26 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet:1214 - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'home'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-03-18 12:49:26 TRACE o.s.w.s.v.JstlView:261 - Rendering view with name 'home' with model {projects=[ (...) ], appVersion=1.1} and static attributes {}
2016-03-18 12:49:26 DEBUG o.s.w.s.v.JstlView:377 - Added model object 'projects' of type [java.util.ArrayList] to request in view with name 'home'
2016-03-18 12:49:26 DEBUG o.s.w.s.v.JstlView:377 - Added model object 'appVersion' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'home'
2016-03-18 12:49:26 DEBUG o.s.w.s.v.JstlView:207 - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'home'
2016-03-18 12:49:26 TRACE o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager:243 - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1b217c9] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@17b412f] from thread [http-nio-8080-exec-1]
2016-03-18 12:49:26 DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor:112 - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2016-03-18 12:49:26 DEBUG o.s.o.j.EntityManagerFactoryUtils:435 - Closing JPA EntityManager
2016-03-18 12:49:26 TRACE o.h.i.SessionImpl:353 - Closing session
2016-03-18 12:49:26 TRACE o.h.e.j.i.JdbcCoordinatorImpl:190 - Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl@d45342]
2016-03-18 12:49:26 TRACE o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl:178 - Closing logical connection
2016-03-18 12:49:26 DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl:246 - Releasing JDBC connection
2016-03-18 12:49:26 DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl:264 - Released JDBC connection
2016-03-18 12:49:26 TRACE o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl:190 - Logical connection closed
2016-03-18 12:49:26 TRACE o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet:1053 - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1b8ac37
2016-03-18 12:49:26 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet:991 - Successfully completed request
2016-03-18 12:49:26 TRACE o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext:331 - Publishing event in org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@121bfd2: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcherServlet]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[390ms]; status=[OK]
```

The controller gets called fine, and it does its job (Such as fetching records from the DB in order to populate the ModelMap (variables `appVersion` and `projects`, which I have redacted to "(...)" ) before returning it) by looking at the log.

The page I'm trying to load works fine when the app has just been started, so the controller itself works (It has been working well always, but I must have introduced a change that caused all this to happen). Stopping and restarting the app in the embedded Tomcat fixes the issue, and upon deploying a WAR to a standalone Linux Tomcat server, the app seems to work well (Half an hour in and no 404s).

Comment: I just wanted, why are using final keyword for 'ProjectOutputService'?

Comment: Mmmh good question. Not sure why, I maybe I copied and pasted something and I forgot to remove it. I'll get rid of it, thanks!

Comment: Did you check the work folder in tomcat home?

Comment: @lenicliu I'm running it through Maven, so I don't know where is the work folder located. Is it under /target on the project folder?

Comment: @fernandopcg Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same issue with spring boot + embedded undertow/tomcat + thymeleaf. Strange thing is that only html resolver stops working after a few minutes, json view resolvers continue on working for some reason.

Comment: @robvelor nope, I kept on using the app with an external Tomcat server, as it's a valid solution for my needs and I didn't get to know why this was happening

Comment: @fernandopcg Ok thanks, I see what the issue is but not sure how to solve it yet. Basically an extra suffix to the template resolver: Resource "classpath:/templates/home.html.html" could not be found... Strange thing is why it works for a few minutes then it just fails.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough info on the original question but as I was facing this exact same issue this was the solution for me:

```
@Bean
public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setOrder(0);
    // viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[] { "*.html", "*.xhtml" });
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Removing `viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[] { "*.html", "*.xhtml" });` fixed the issue.

Once I set the logging level to trace I was able to see the problem:
`Resource "classpath:/templates/home.html.html was not found"`
There were two suffixes being added to the templates. As to why it worked for a few minutes before failing is still a mystery to me.

Hope this helps someone.