# Why the template resolver stop working after a few days?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I created and java web app using the following

- jdk version 1.8
- spring version 4.2.0.RELEASE
- jstl version 1.2
- thymeleaf version 2.1.3.RELEASE

It uses spring boot and I run it with jetty runner.

Everything works fine, the problem is that after keep the application running a few days (around 15 days) spring has problems resolving the views and when you open the application you get a 500 error followed by the  below trace

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "scanMasterView", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:245)
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
   at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
   at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:364)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't think the problem comes from jetty, I'm not sure whether it is spring or thymeleaf.

if I restart the application it works fine again for another 15 days, I was monitoring the memory usage looking for leaks but all is fine, it is only that the resolver stops working after those days without give more info about the crash

Have you experienced this problem before? any clue?

Edit:
this is how the template resolver is configured

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Is working time a constant time (exactly 15 days and 3 hours) or it can vary? Also what env are you running server on? x86? If I were you, I would probably try to run server on another machine as well for 16 days to check if it's machine or code specific. I guess it's not that hard to setup another env with spring-boot.

Comment: it varies, sometimes 2 weeks, others 3 weeks, the thing is that I need to restart it once a month to keep it working

Comment: Did you try stress test, perhaps it stops working after certain amount of requests. If you use some services (like database, or mb you have some open socket that hangs) Something like that could be also be a cause.

Comment: I will give it a try with some stress tests, one thing I was thinking is that perhaps during the execution and because jetty runner extracts the content of war to a temp location some files "might" get lost

2017-05-19 14:00:22.572:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3c679bde{/,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-1312-app.war-dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:/app/app.war}

but  it's just a guest

Comment: is that the full trace?

Comment: no, the full trace is what is on the question, acctualy this is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084739/spring-boot-stops-resolving-views-after-a-few-minutes but it has no answers